# Magnitude of Error vs. Model Precision

Tags: regression, model, linear

In a simple linear regression model, is it safe to make a broad statement that the magnitude of the error is rooted in summing residuals and the precision of the model is rooted in the distribution of the residuals?

Comment: A simple linear regression model (with an intercept) will have the sum of the residuals equal zero, so something is not right here.

Comment: I should have been clearer and say rooted in summing the squares of residuals.